# My IBM PS/2 Model 80 (8580-071) comes up with errors

Tags: ibm-ps2

First of all, the ram loads up fine. But I get these errors:

```
301
161
163
```

Right before the `163` error, there are two audible beeps, both short.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also, here is the battery that I need to change on the computer? I know that one of the errors is because of a dead battery.

Comment: Just to say - we have a [retrocomputing site](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com) now, and this might be a great option for future questions, simply cause it kind of concentrates folks who know about, well older hardware. I'd suggest splitting off the latter part, about the battery, fattening it up a bit, ans asking there.

Answer (score 2):

Google can do wonders: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ibm+8580+error+codes

The [top result](http://ps-2.kev009.com/pcpartnerinfo/ctstips/49fe.htm) has a list of the error codes:

- 301 - Keyboard did not respond to software reset correctly or a stuck key failure was detected. If a stuck key was detected, the scan code for the key is displayed (as "301 xx" or "xx-0301").
- 161 - AT systems options not set (run SETUP). PS/2 - Battery dead or not connected
- 163 - AT time & date not set (run SETUP). PCC - Real-time clock not updating

Two short beeps appears to indicate "*nonfatal errors found*".

Many systems require that you "*Press F1 to continue*" or similar, so check the display for any hints.